# can't access a previously defined node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the following code snippet. In that i define the node (B) with the `coordinate` operation. Unfortunately i can't access the node later on. LuaLatex exits with the error message:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known.
```

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

        \tikzset{%
            auto/.pic={%
                \draw[fill=black!20] (0,10pt)
                    node[fill=black!20,anchor=south,
                            draw,rectangle,
                            minimum width=3cm,
                            minimum height=0.75cm] (-A) {};

                \draw[fill=black]
                    ($(-A.south west)!0.2!(-A.south east)$) circle (10pt);
                \draw[fill=black] 
                    ($(-A.south west)!0.8!(-A.south east)$) circle (10pt);
            }
        }

        % define node (B)
        \draw[rotate=30,every node/.style={rotate=30}] 
            (0,0) coordinate (A) -- 
            (4,0) pic (Auto) {auto} -- 
            (8,0) coordinate (B);

        \draw[->, line width=1pt] 
            (Auto-A.center) -- +(0,-2) node[midway,right]{$\vec F$};

        % can't access (B)
        \draw (A) -- (B);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Keep the `pic` inside braces; `{pic (Auto) {auto}}`. It turns on the picture syntax but doesn't turn off so braces limit the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pair of braces around the `Auto` pic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,]

        \tikzset{%
            auto/.pic={%
                \draw[fill=black!20] (0,10pt)
                    node[fill=black!20,anchor=south,
                            draw,rectangle,
                            minimum width=3cm,
                            minimum height=0.75cm] (-A) {};
                \draw[fill=black]
                    ($(-A.south west)!0.2!(-A.south east)$) circle (10pt);
                \draw[fill=black] 
                    ($(-A.south west)!0.8!(-A.south east)$) circle (10pt);
            }
        }

        % define node (B)
        \draw[rotate=30,every node/.style={rotate=30}] 
            (0,0) coordinate (A) -- 
            (4,0) {pic (Auto) {auto}} -- 
            (8,0) coordinate (B);

        \draw[->, line width=1pt] 
            (Auto-A.center) -- +(0,-2) node[midway,right]{$\vec F$};

        % can access (B)
        \draw (A) -- (B);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok we need a photo finish for this :)

Comment: @percusse  Indeed! :)